When is a degree-$n$ homogeneous polynomial in $\mathbb{C}[x_1, x_2, \ldots , x_m ]$ the product of $n$ one-forms?
When is a degree-$n$ homogeneous polynomial in $\mathbb{C}[x_1, x_2, \ldots , x_m ]$ the product of $n$ one-forms?
Is there any simple algorithm or criterion to check it?
I have chosen the complex field to avoid any field insufficiency.

Does this answer your question? which homogeneous polynomials split into linear factors?

@GjergjiZaimi Not obvious to me that it does. The current question is specifically about sub-question 4. of that question, and it looks like that sub-question was left unanswered.

This is set theoretically defined by Brill's equations for the Chow variety, although the ideal they generate is not in general radical.

I think i did answer that question.

@R.P.: Q4 is rather moot. As far as I know, the simplest criterion is the answer to Q3, i.e., to just plug the coefficients of the polynomial of interest into the Brill-Gordan equations and see if one gets zero or not.
